# How to combine my URL with data from my MYSQL

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a database linked to the project with the variable {{PID}}.
What I want is to create a function to open external files (URL) that contain this expression in the middle:
To open a single file I have:

```
<ion-button (click)="abrirpdf('https://abcd.com/pids/RS-00020.pdf')">Open {{PID}}</ion-button>
```

I would like to know how to integrate the variable in my URL if possible, because it doesn't work this way:

```
<ion-button (click)="abrirpdf('https://abcd.com/pids/RS-{{PID}}.pdf')">Open {{PID}}</ion-button>


TS:
abrirpdf(url:string){

  window.open(url, '_system', 'location=yes');
}
```

Comment: Please post the contents of the related component containing the arbrirpdf function. But basically you could either do the concatenation in the function itself or inline it here like abrirpdf('https://abcd.com/pids/RS-`${PID}`.pdf')   note that stackoverflow editor is being annoying and removing the https

Comment: Thanks for your help. Very grateful. I modify but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already know the PID do it like so.

```
abrirpdf(){

  const myUrl = 'https://abcd.com/pids/RS-' + PID + '.pdf';
  window.open(myUrl, '_system', 'location=yes');
}
```

And your HTML

```
<ion-button (click)="abrirpdf()">Open {{PID}}</ion-button>
```

I suspect you really are iterating over the object, in which case, just pass in the string value of PID into the function.